# Page navigation for webapi

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Here I need to develop a jquery site for Asp.net Web Api. However every time i run the web api application it opens the index page.. But how to create a new view page for this web api which connects to my own controller say products..Or else How to link the new page from the default index page. Please you can even refer me any tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this write-up - [Your First ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)?